# Why Image rotate after capturing from Camera and send to another activity?

Tags: android, image, orientation

My image rotate when I use camera Intent . After capturing picture my I send this picture to another activity by using Intent and set this pic as background of Layout but capturing picture in landscape rotate the picture.

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: Use glide to display image

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using the `ExitInterface` shown below:

```
private void setPic(Uri contentUri) throws IOException {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = uploadedImage.getWidth();
        int targetH = uploadedImage.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bmOptions, targetW, targetH);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        bitmap = rotateImageIfRequired(bitmap, contentUri);
        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, 750, 750);
        uploadedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

This function is where the bitmap is being decoded based on the path in the phone, it is then calling the `rotateImageIfRequired()` which will determine which way the image should rotate before it is set to the background of your layout. In this scenario `uploadedImage` is your layout.

```
private Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Bitmap img, Uri contentUri) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(contentUri.getPath());
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotateImage(img, 90);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotateImage(img, 180);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotateImage(img, 270);
            default:
                return img;
        }
    }
```

This function will determine which orientation the image is after it has been decoded and before it has been set.

```
 private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        img.recycle();
        return rotatedImg;
    }
```

This function rotates the image and returns the new image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: did this help at all?